# Custom Search Lightning component cannot read property. (community)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, ajax

I have been trying to implement a custom search in communities whereby the user can type in the first line of the address and the search will update with each keystroke. But I receive this error:

> Action failed: c$ContactList$controller$searchKeyChange [Cannot read
>   property 'setParams' of null] Failing descriptor:
>   {c$ContactList$controller$searchKeyChange}

The code in question is below.

**ContactList.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="ContactListController">

<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="account[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:handler event="c:SearchKeyChange" action="{!c.searchKeyChange}"/>

<ul>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
        <li>
            <a href="{! '#/sObject/' + account.Id + '/view'}">
                <p>{!account.Name}</p>
                <p>{!account.Phone}</p>
                <p>{!account.BillingStreet}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </aura:iteration>
</ul>
```

**ContactListController.js**

```
({
doInit : function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.findAll");
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        component.set("v.accounts", a.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},


searchKeyChange: function(component, event) {
var searchKey = event.getParam("searchKey");
var action = component.get("e.c.findAll");
action.setParams({
  "searchKey": searchKey
});
action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    component.set("v.accounts", a.getReturnValue());
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

**SearchBar.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
           placeholder="Search" onkeyup="{!c.searchKeyChange}"/>
</div>
```

**SearchBarController.js**

```
({
searchKeyChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:SearchKeyChange");
    myEvent.setParams({"searchKey":event.target.value});
    myEvent.fire();
}
})
```

**SearchKeyChange.evt**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <aura:attribute name="searchKey" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is. Any feedback would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that findAll is the remote method in your controller, I believe that your line in **ContactListController.js**:

```
var action = component.get("e.c.findAll");
```

should be:

```
var action = component.get("c.findAll");
```

This is causing the action to be null and the reference to setParams to throw an error.